# Upgrading spring boot : Rest Template Bean Creation failed because of circular dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am updating spring boot app from 1.5.6.Release to 2.3.5 but getting exception while building project.
Following is my error class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({BatchScheduler.class})
public class MyLogBatchConfiguration {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VToolLogBatchConfiguration.class);

  @Autowired private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "dataSource1")
  public DataSource mainDataSource;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "dataSource2")
  public DataSource tempDataSource;

  @Autowired public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  
  @Autowired private RestTemplate myRestTemplate;

  @Qualifier(value = "createLocalSessionFactory")
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory createLocalSessionFactory;

  @Qualifier(value = "createSessionFactory")
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory createSessionFactory;

  @Bean
  RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
      if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter =
            (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
            ImmutableList.of(
                new MediaType(
                    "application", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET),
                new MediaType(
                    "text", "javascript", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
      }
    }
    return restTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean createLocalSessionFactory(
      @Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] {
          "X",
          "Y",
          "Z"
        });
    factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean createSessionFactory(
      @Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] {
          "X",
          "Y",
          "Z"
        });
    factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return factory;
  }
```

I am getting following error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'MyLogBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'myRestTemplate'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'myRestTemplate'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource
> [com/***********/configuration/MyLogBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ] at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'myRestTemplate'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource
> [com/******/configuration/MyLogBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 28 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource
> [com/******/configuration/MyLogBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 50 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
> ... 63 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
> org.springframework.util.MimeType.(MimeType.java:143)   at
> org.springframework.http.MediaType.(MediaType.java:433)

I have omitted some in-between stack trace to keep important lines
It was working fine in 1.5.6.Release version.
I dont see any cyclic dependency here.RestTemplate function also does not depend on MyLogBatchConfiguration. I also tried to change the order and put myRestTemplate bean after createSessionFactory bean and still only restTemplate call fails and not other.It seems other created successfully. Why is it happening in upgrade? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your configuration has an `@Bean` method to creates the `RestTemplate` and the `RestTemplate` is also injected in the same `@Configuration`. Hence a circular dependency. Don't autowire beans in the same configuration that creates them, as that is a circular dependency.

Comment: ok but 1.) ts working fine in 1.5.6 boot version 2.) for other beans named createLocalSessionFactory and createSessionFactory, it does not throw any error ,why so?

Comment: because it never gets to the latter 2. I'm surprised it even worked, which is more out of luck then that it was a feature.

Comment: hey, acutually i think the cause for cyclic dependency is

Comment: Because of NullPointerException in last two lines because of MediaType problem.I have posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66746643/nullpointerexception-mediatype-in-resttemplate-spring-boot, can you help here?

Comment: No it isn't it is a result of your circular dependency. You shouldn't inject a bean in the same class that creates it.