# NullPointerException MediaType in RestTemplate Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-rest

I am updating spring boot app from 1.5.6.Release to 2.3.5 but getting exception while building project.
Following is my error class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Import({BatchScheduler.class})
public class MyLogBatchConfiguration {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLogBatchConfiguration.class);

  @Autowired private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "dataSource1")
  public DataSource mainDataSource;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "dataSource2")
  public DataSource tempDataSource;

  @Autowired public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  
  @Autowired private RestTemplate myRestTemplate;

  @Qualifier(value = "createLocalSessionFactory")
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory createLocalSessionFactory;

  @Qualifier(value = "createSessionFactory")
  @Autowired
  private SessionFactory createSessionFactory;

  @Bean
  RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> converter : converters) {
      if (converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter =
            (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter;
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
            ImmutableList.of(
                new MediaType(
                    "application", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET),
                new MediaType(
                    "text", "javascript", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET)));
      }
    }
    return restTemplate;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean createLocalSessionFactory(
      @Qualifier("dataSource1") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] {
          "X",
          "Y",
          "Z"
        });
    factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalSessionFactoryBean createSessionFactory(
      @Qualifier("dataSource2") DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setPackagesToScan(
        new String[] {
          "X",
          "Y",
          "Z"
        });
    factory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return factory;
  }
```

I am getting following error :
:

```
> 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'MyLogBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'myRestTemplate'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'myRestTemplate'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource
> [com//configuration/MyLogBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation
> via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ] at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107)
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'myRestTemplate'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource
> [com//configuration/MyLogBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation
> via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 28 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in class path resource
> [com/*/configuration/MyLogBatchConfiguration.class]: Bean
> instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
> ... 50 common frames omitted Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]: Circular
> reference involving containing bean 'MyLogBatchConfiguration' -
> consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from
> its containing instance. Factory method 'restTemplate' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
> ... 63 common frames omitted Caused by:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
> org.springframework.util.MimeType.(MimeType.java:143) at
> org.springframework.http.MediaType.(MediaType.java:433)
```

I have omitted some in-between stack trace to keep important lines. It was working fine in **1.5.6** Release version.
The main reason is the last line, where it works with

> MimeType.java MediaType.Java

and throws Null Pointer Exception.How can I pass MediaTypes correctly ? I do see a warning in eclipse as :

```
The field AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET is 
 deprecated
```

Any workaround of handling Null Media type is appreciated.

Comment: Can you mention the complete stack trace please

Comment: i have updated.Plz let me know if  u need more info. I earlier thought it is cyclic dependency issue as mentioned in some stack trace but i tried removing that ,still the error persists, then i saw at bottom of logs, i got some MediaType Null pointer Exception and thats why restTemplate Bean is not getting created.

Comment: Have look at this post and see if this helps and let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525387/mockmvc-no-longer-handles-utf-8-characters-with-spring-boot-2-2-0-release

Comment: I have updated the link in above comment

Comment: I replaced MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.DEFAULT_CHARSET statement with StandardCharsets.UTF_8, but still it give same error.The link was suppose to do this only .right?

Comment: Yeh, I think so. Also the way the support is added for text/json. Why you need mutable list?

Comment: what exactly can be problem.Is it circular dependency it shows or is it Media type null pointer at bottom?My guess is media type only, but am i looking into write direction?

Comment: Both can be the issue, first look into the circular dependency error That is appearing and needs to be resolved first. Check for correct compatibility version of ja for spring and jackson

Comment: @Sohan, the link you share has resolved my problem.I had to clean and build again.I did not clean it earlier.Thanks.

Comment: Should I add that as solution here?

Comment: yes u can add here.

Comment: Please check and accept if it looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem from 2.2.0 spring-boot. They set deprecation for default charset encoding.

Try replacing with followingFor both type. json and text,

```
new MediaType("application", "json", MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```